# How can I change the color of the Navigation Bar < and word in iOS and Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application uses a tab page and when I push a new page then a back navigation arrow appears with a word to the right of it.

In iOS it's blue.  How can I change the color of this arrow and the text with Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is tied to the `BarTextColor` of the `NavigationPage`.

You can change the text by setting the `Title` of each page, that is what is shown by default. You can also change this by setting it through the `SetBackButtonTitle(Page, string)` method.